# In Android, if it took more than 16 ms to complete the work to draw a frame, when is the next frame actually ready?

Tags: android, graphics

To be specific, I'll present my question in an example:

Say at t = 0 ms, a frame was completed and became visible to the user on the screen. From that point on, I began the work to draw the next frame. However, the work took too long that I missed the frame's due time of t = 16 ms. If finally this next frame was ready at t = 23 ms. When would it actually be visible to the user? t = 23 ms or t = 32 ms (at the next drawing "heart beat" if any)?

And also, where in the Android source code can I find the answer myself?

Comment: You need to share some code... What do you mean in `where in the Android source code can I find the answer myself?` ?

Comment: Watch Google IO 2012 For Butter or Worse: https://youtu.be/Q8m9sHdyXnE The session covers when Google made improvements to the graphics and animation systems.

Comment: @DeividiCavarzan This is a question on how the Android graphics system is working. My code works fine. I just want to know Android better. I mean where in the Android Open Source Project codebase can I find the implementation of the timing logic.

Answer (score 2):

You actually get 16.666ms per frame, so if you aren't ready to draw at that point then the next attempt would be made at 34ms. Colt from Google has a good video explaining this actually. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HXQhu6qfTVU